# Camel - How to log select query in camel route using java dsl, when using MYBATIS component?

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis

I want to log the select query before calling database for better readability of log for reference. I am using mybatis component. I want to know, if there is any inbuilt camel header or mybatis component header can be used log the query.

```
**CAMEL ROUTE**
from("timer://pollTheDatabase?delay=50s")
.routeId("db-pooling-route")
.to("mybatis:queryToSelectData?statementType=SelectOne");

**MAPPER**
@Mapper
public interface DBMapper{
   public void queryToSelectData();
}

**MAPPER XML**
<select id="queryToSelectData" resultMap="Result">
    SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT AND ROWNUM =1
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very brief knowledge of the mybatis component, so my answer might not be exact! Camel does not give an inbuilt option to capture the mybatis query. You only have an option to get the statement name. However, could you please log the body just before sending the query and check?

If the body doesn't have the query string, this is how I would do it. In order to get the query string, you could implement a bean where you would need to import the mybatis mapper file and extract the information you require. You could then write it to the log from the bean itself, or you could add it to the Exchange properties.